# Problem with pic24f code

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm trying to write some code that waits for a pin to change before continuing but it doesn't work. The code that I already have is:

```
do{
    LATBbits.LATB6=1;

}while(PORTBbits.RB14== 0);       

LATBbits.LATB6=0; ... d something else
```

The RB14 pin is already configured as an input.
I want it to wait until RB14 is high before continuing the code execution. I'm using a pic24f16ka102 microcontroller.

Comment: That looks reasonable. Perhaps the error is elsewhere. Have you verified that you are reading pin 14 OK?

Comment: Does that PIC have ANSEL registers and if it does, have you configured them correctly to make the port digital and not analog?

Comment: When you _do_ get it working you should modify the code to avoid the `do ... while` wait loop. That construction is simple but ties up the processor and prevents it doing anything else.

Comment: Your intent is not entirely clear. Are you trying to execute the code in the do...while loop when RB14 changes, or do you want to set LATB6, then wait until RB14 is high, and then clear LATB6?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set LATB6 and then wait until RB14 is high before continuing then you don't want a do-while loop. You would want something like this:

```
LATBbits.LATB6 = 1;           //set LATB6
while(PORTBbits.RB14 == 0);   //wait until RB14 is HIGH
LATBbits.LATB6 = 0;           //execute other code
```

I don't quite understand why you have `LATBbits.LATB6 = 1` inside a do-while loop. While theoretically it does the same thing, it just wastes time and resources. It keeps setting LATB6 over and over again until RB14 is HIGH, but there is no need to keep setting LATB6 to the same value -- It keeps its previous state.

This probably isn't your problem though. I expect your issue is that you have not disabled the ADC (analog-digital converter). RB14 shares a pin with AN10 (analog input 10). Some pics default to analog input, which is not what you want. you need to actively disable the ADC in order for RB14 to be a digital input.

Comment: the error was that the rb14 was configured as analog pin